# SQL Join with no records found

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

so I'm trying to do a join using just one table with multiple selects.

The table I'm using looks like this...

```
    Floor No. | Apartment No. | Bathroom No. | Size
        1     |       1       |       1      |  30
        1     |       1       |       2      |  20
        1     |       2       |       1      |  30
        1     |       2       |       2      |  40
        1     |       2       |       3      |  60
        2     |       1       |       1      |  30
        2     |       1       |       2      |  20
        2     |       2       |       1      |  30
        2     |       2       |       2      |  40
        2     |       2       |       3      |  60
```

So basically, each floor has a number of apartments, and each apartment has a number of bathrooms with different sizes.    I'm trying to return results which look something like this..

```
    Floor No. | APT1A | APT1B | APT2A | APT2B | APT2C
       1      |   30  |   20  |   30  |   40  |   60
       2      |   30  |   20  |   30  |   40  |   60
```

So far I've gotten this SQL statement which works..

```
    SELECT DISTINCT A.FloorNumber, B.Size As APT1A, C.Size AS APT1B 
    FROM BathroomTable A
    inner join BathroomTable B on a.FloorNumber  = B.FloorNumber
    inner outer join BathroomTable C on a.FloorNumber = C.FloorNumber
    WHERE b.ApartmentNumber = 'APT1' AND b.BathroomNumber = 1
    AND (C.ApartmentNumber = 'APT1' AND C.BathroomNumber = 2)
```

And so on with the joins, which will work as long as I am joining records which exist in the database..  However, sometimes there will be only one bathroom in apartment 1, and the sql query will try to find the data for the second bathroom, and then no results will be returned.  Is there any way to insert null values if its not found?

Thanks, I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do..

Comment: Use a `left join` instead of an `inner join` to return rows from the left-hand table even if no match is found in the right-hand table.  (+1 to compensate for the downvote... SO is a hostile place for new users these days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.FloorNumber, B.Size As APT1A, C.Size AS APT1B 
FROM ApartementTable A
inner join BathroomTable B on a.ApartmentNumber  = B.ApartmentNumber AND b.BathroomNumber = 1
LEFT join BathroomTable C on a.ApartmentNumber = C.ApartmentNumber AND C.BathroomNumber = 2
WHERE A.ApartmentNumber = 'APT1'
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried this just before you posted and got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.FloorNumber, B.Size As APT1A, C.Size AS APT1B 
FROM BathroomTable A
OUTER join BathroomTable B on a.FloorNumber  = B.FloorNumber
OUTER join BathroomTable C on a.FloorNumber = C.FloorNumber
WHERE b.ApartmentNumber = 'APT1' AND b.BathroomNumber = 1 AND (C.ApartmentNumber = 'APT1' AND C.BathroomNumber = 2)
```